# How to get data from data model via constant

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using `Spring boot` and `Thymeleaf` as a template framework. I set a couple constants on the backend and I need to get data on the frontend via that constants.
I have the backend look like the following:

```
public class Constant {
    public static final String MY_VAR = "test";
}

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add("item1");
        model.addAttribute(Constant.MY_VAR, data);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

and on the frontend I want to do like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">

    <div th:unless="${not #lists.isEmpty(Constant.MY_VAR)}"> 

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I get access to model data via constant from the backend?

Comment: this might help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-objects-js

Comment: ${not #lists.isEmpty('test')} can solve your problem

Comment: Constant is not passed to front end

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ModelAndView ** to solve this problem

- backend

```java
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add("item1");
        modelAndView.addObject("test", data);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

- frontend

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div th:if="${test.size() > 0}">
        <li th:each="item:${test}">
            <span th:text="${item}"></span>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want get static attribute in your view。

you can do that

```
${T(packageName.Constant).MY_VAR}
```

so u can change your code

```
${not #lists.isEmpty(Constant.MY_VAR)}
```

to

```
${not #lists.isEmpty(#ctx.getVariable(T(packageName.Constant).MY_VAR))}
```